# Does controlling 2 or more motors needs a regulator?

Tags: motor, l293d

I have successfully controlled my stepper motor with a L293D and Arduino. 
Now I want to add more motors (up to 3) each with it's own L293D driver. 
I'm using a *single* separate power supply for the motors. 
Will I need a regulator to stabilize the voltage and if yes why? 
The motors won't rotate/step at the same time. The motors are low powered 5V - 9V.

Comment: Why not just use a single supply that can supply sufficient current for all of them?

Comment: Yes that is what i mean. I use a single power supply for all the motors. Do i need a regulator?

Comment: Do you understand what a regulator does?

Comment: Not really. I think if you draw more current or voltage it stabilizes the supply

Comment: @JohnAm, you might want to clarify what you mean by "work" in your statement "The [stepper] motors won't work at the same time." Current flows continuously through a stepper motor's windings when the motor is energized and the shaft is stationary or stepping/rotating.

Comment: I mean "rotating/stepping". Does a stepper uses the same amount of current when rotating and when is stationary? Can you point me to an article that discusses how 2-3 motors preferably steppers, operate in relation to a single power supply. Also with the l293D. Does it act as a regulator? I'm trying to understand this part.

Comment: A stepper motor's windings draw current continuously from the power supply. When the motor's shaft is stationary, the winding current is what holds the shaft in its present position in opposition to an applied torque load on the shaft.

Comment: "Also with the [L293D]. Does it act as a regulator?" No, it doesn't act as a voltage regulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the entire system, it is impossible to answer your question definitively.  However, it seems UNLIKELY that you need a regulator just because of the additional stepper motors.  Since they are stepper motors, they aren't very dependent on voltage anyway. And if only one will be operating at a time, then there seems like little or no benefit.   Of course if there are OTHER parts of the circuit that need stable voltage, that is a different question (or at least a question broader than the one you asked.)